# Javascript not working inside asp.net checkbox list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

show/hide javascript not working when we click on checkbox in asp.net. I have using the following code.

**Code snippets:**

```
 <div class="prod-filter-nav">
 <h4>Category</h4>
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1"  runat="server" class="prod-list"  
 AutoPostBack="True"   RepeatLayout="UnorderedList">
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
 </div>
```

The following javascript used for this page:--

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.prod-filter-nav h4').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('closed').siblings('.prod-list').slideToggle(300);
    })
});
```

javascript not working when we select any of the checkbox item

Answer (score 4):

use jquery change event [(https://api.jquery.com/change/)](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
 $('#CheckBoxList1').change(function () {
        //your code here
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The click handler works on the click of `<h4>` element

```
$('.prod-filter-nav h4').on('click'
```

and not on the checkbox item click.
I'd suggest that you should change the associated click handler to the check-box item level.

Answer (score 0):

try this : with `ClientID` and remove `AutoPostBack="True"`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID%>').change(function () {
            //place your js code here
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to select input[type=checkbox], but as @Ganesh_Devlekar answerd first you have to remove AutoPostBack if you dont need it, and you said you want to fire event when click on checkbox not on H4 click, so I will sugest this code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.prod-filter-nav input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
        $(this).closest(".prod-filter-nav").toggleClass('closed').siblings('.prod-list').slideToggle(300);
    })
});
```

But first you have to be sure of javascript selector

Comment: i cant hide that div after select any of the checkbox item, if i don't select checkbox i can hide that div when i click on h4